# for loop to print frequency table when freq > 3

Tags: r, for-loop

With the following example, I wish to scan each row of `B`, and out the values **only once** if they appear more than three times. I have tried with the following for loop, but not been successful yet.

```
set.seed(123456)

B = matrix( sample(1:100, 100, replace = T), 
            nrow=10,
            ncol=10)

for(i=1:nrow(B)){
  which(table(B[i,])>3){
    NA
  }
  print(i)
}
```

The desired output is a list of the appropriate values from each row

Comment: example changed, so a more consistent answer can be found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
apply(B, 1, function(x) as.numeric(names(table(x)[which(table(x) > 3)])))
```

or, as per ProcrastinatusMaximus' comment, a shorter version:

```
apply(B, 1, function(x) as.integer(names(which(table(x) > 3))))
```

Comment: you don't really need `which` here. You could do `apply(B,1,function(x) as.numeric(names(table(x)>3)))`

Comment: I'd disagree, names() will select all the names regardless of T/F state. We have to select only the ones that fit the condition. Ex : `as.numeric(names(table(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2))>3))` returns 1 and 2 when it should return 1.

Comment: I stand corrected. I got mislead by `identical(apply(B,1,function(x) as.numeric(names(table(x)>3))), apply(B,1,function(x) as.numeric(names(table(x)[which(table(x)>3)]))))`

Comment: a bit shorter: `apply(B, 1, function(x) as.integer(names(which(table(x) > 3))))`

Answer (score 1):

This does not keep it in each row, but it might worth looking into the package used (`matrixStats`)

```
library(matrixStats)
as.numeric(colnames(rowTabulates(B)>3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Using `melt` from 'data.table' convert to 'long' format, convert to 'data.table' (`setDT(...)`), grouped by 'Var1', 'value', we get the frequency count only `if` the count is greater than 3.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(B))[, if(.N > 3) .N, .(Var1, value)]
```